# How to create a vector from 2 merged matrices in R and fill in any dimension gaps with NA's?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, dimensions

Suppose I have a 4x4 matrix generated as shown in the image below for `mat1`. (Image is from a snapshot of R Studio Console). Suppose I have another matrix generated of any size for example (1x2 in the below image for `mat2`). (In my code, the matrix elements and dimensions vary for both of the above matrices based on user inputs; though columns are only generated in multiples of 2, so I can have a [ ]x2 matrix, [ ]x4, [ ]x6, etc., and number of rows can be any integer).

In my code these 2 matrices are merged into a vector (a vector is required for processing via R package `shinyMatrix`).

Since these 2 matrix dimensions are variable, there are instances when merging the 2 matrices into a vector where you don't end up with the correct number of elements for converting back to a "dimensionable" matrix. As shown in the below image for `mat3`, where there are 18 elements after combining the 2 matrices `mat1` and `mat2` and certain elements must be dropped and NA's inserted to end up with a 4x4, 16 element matrix in this example.

There are instances where `mat2` can have more elements than `mat1`. In this example I show `mat1` with 16 elements and `mat2` with 2 elements.

Importantly, in the code only the first 2 columns of `mat1` can ever be replaced in this way with `mat2` values. Columns 3+ of `mat1` are never changed by `mat2`.

Is there an efficient way to code this? Where you fit 2 matrices together into the dimensions of the larger matrix, and fill in any missing elements with NA?

I'm going down the path of measuring the length of `mat1` columns 1 and 2, measuring the length of `mat2` columns 1 and 2, merging, replacing elements, etc., but with my limited experience it's looking very cumbersome and not working quite right. I bet R has a slick way to accomplish this sort of thing. One of the `apply` functions, like `mapply`? I read somewhere `mapply` is great for subsetting matrices.`Tibbles`?

Here are my matrix inputs for the below image:

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(1,2,NA,NA, 3,4,NA,NA, 5:12), ncol = 4)
mat2 <- matrix(c(10,30), ncol = 2)
mat3 <- c(mat2,mat1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the expected output, we may select the columns in 'mat1', that doesn't have `anyNA` and concatenate (`c`) with the `length` corrected columns by appending `NA` at the end in 'mat2'

```
c(sapply(mat2, `length<-`, nrow(mat1)), mat1[,!apply(mat1, 2, anyNA)])
[1] 10 NA NA NA 30 NA NA NA  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Hi akrun, the output needs to be [10 NA NA NA 30 NA NA NA 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]. Sorry I need to revise my post and image above to correctly reflect this.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 do you need the one in the update

Comment: Yes the updated image, in my comment in the bottom right corner of the image, shows the desired output. Which matches what you just posted in your solution using sapply. Let me take a look, it's FAR FAR cleaner than where I was going with this.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 I didn't read your whole description.  I constructed the code based on the expected output you created

Comment: Yes your solution works great! And understandable. The apply functions really provide a tremendous shortcut, they are worth learning